# Mongoose compatible ith Windows 8 r2

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I've been trying to get mongoose to work on windows 8 r2. Does anyone know of why this is not working? I have I working on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8 r2. Any thoughts would be appreciated. To be more specific I am not able to access localhost80 or localhost82 through my browser...I use the exact same setup on Windows 7 and it accesses it just fine... I turn off firewall and still no look in accessing the localhost. Thank You advance for any assistance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What did you try, what went wrong?

Comment: The problem is that it will not display the content of the server in the browser...shows page cannot be found.

Comment: Did you check firewall ? listening port ?